# Lua function syntax sugar for a digit started name

Tags: syntax, lua

Lua 5.1.4

For example:

```
bar = {}
bar.name = 'test'
bar['123.com'] = function(self) print(self.name) end
```

I can't call the method like below:

```
bar:['123.com']()
stdin:1: '<name>' expected near '['
```

Althought below works:

```
bar['123.com'](bar)
```

But I this is somehow ugly. Is there a syntax sugar for this situation?

Or if it really cannot do it, will Lua team add this syntax in future?

Or they did this intentionally?

Comment: Making method calls via square brackets is already pretty ugly (e.g. `bar['x']` rather than `bar.x`). I doubt the parser will ever be extended to handle this case.

Comment: But some time, it's really better to use a name started with digit.

Comment: Is it? That doesn't look like what you're doing here: this looks like a table driven approach to something, in which case you're going to be doing `object[selector](object)` anyway. In what other scenario would you want a method named "123.com"?

Comment: I am writing a lib to parse some websites. Their names can be really strange (even can have some Asia characters), it's better not to translate them into english, or it's hard to do so. I want to treat them a same way no matter what the names are like.

Comment: Right, so that's implies a data driven approach where I'd want to use `table[selector]` anyhoo. \*shrug\* In any case, I'm a huge fan of Lua and try to use it for everything I can, but if you have a web scraping chore I'd highly recommend checking out Mechanize (Perl, Python, Ruby, perhaps others) which is like having a GUI-less programmable browser with a queryable DOM. Make stuff like this a breeze. I wish Lua was part of the club that has all this library support, but alas (I blame it's module system >.>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody knows what the Lua maintainers will add in future versions (they're pretty close-mouthed), but my guess would be that it's unlikely they'll add it without at least being asked—and I've never seen a request for such a thing on the Lua mailing list...

My intuition, though, is that this functionality seems obscure: how often do people really want to call methods with "weird" names like that?  Given that, and that the "workaround" really isn't bad at all, it's unclear whether it's worth adding complexity to the implementation to support such a feature (unless it's completely trivial).

If you want to try asking, you should post about it to the Lua mailing list, which is where most such discussion takes place:  `lua-l@lists.lua.org`

Comment: I think any language should always persist in its syntax style. Or they did this intentionally? And thanks, I'll try to mail them.

Answer (score 7):

No we can not call the method like you want. Your suppose to call the method as following syntax only.

```
bar['123.com'](bar)
```

Comment: This is not what I want, I already wrote them in my question. Please don't repeat.

Answer (score 4):

Just make an alias that doesn't begin with numbers and use that.

```
bar.name123 = bar['123name']

bar:name123()
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider something like below (you can test online at http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo):

```
bar = {}
bar.name = 'test'
bar['123.com'] = function(self) print(self.name) end

bar2 = setmetatable({}, {
  __index = function(t, key)
    return function(...)
      return bar[key](bar, ...)
    end
  end
})

bar2['123.com']()
-- output: test
```

You can also change `bar` itself to behave in a similar way, only you must do it before you assign any values - e.g.:

```
bar = {}

local privatekey = {}
setmetatable(bar, {
  __index = function(t, key)
    local value = rawget(t, privatekey)[key]
    if type(value) ~= 'function' then
      return value
    end
    return function(...)
      return value(t, ...)
    end
  end,
  __newindex = function(t, key, value)
    rawset(t, privatekey, rawget(t, privatekey) or {})
    rawget(t, privatekey)[key] = value
  end
})

bar.name = 'test'
bar['123.com'] = function(self) print(self.name) end
bar['123.com']()
-- output: test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [closure](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html):

```
bar = {}
bar.name = 'test'
bar['123.com'] = function() print(bar.name) end
bar['123.com']()

function bar:addBar(name)
    bar[name] = function() print(self.name) end
end

bar:addBar('456.com')

bar['456.com']()
```

Comment: That works only in very limited circumstances. It won't call it on the particular instance, so you'd have to create a new function for every instance you create.

Comment: The use case given was limited. I've elaborated on the example.

Comment: Then the answer is no, there is no syntactic sugar but you can use other methods to make it act like there is.

Comment: @Nicol: you'd have to create a new *closure* for every instance, but only one function. Just clarifying that because I learned that very recently.

Answer (score 1):

Oh god...

```
bar = {
    ['123.com'] = function(self)
        print("YAY!", self)
    end
}
function f()
    print(bar)
    bar:WHATTHE()
end

function crazy(f, patt, repl)
    local f_str = string.dump(f)
    local newf_str = string.gsub(f_str, "WHATTHE", "123.com")
    assert(#newf_str == #f_str, "replacement must be of same length")
    local newf = loadstring(newf_str)
    setfenv(newf, getfenv(f))
    return newf
end

f = crazy(f, "WHATTHE", "123.com")

f()
--[[ Output:
    table: 005EB688
    YAY!    table: 005EB688
]]
```

Don't do this - **ever**.